# Creating shape keys of armature's preserve volume

Tags: armature, shape-keys

Since preserve volume doesn't export out of blender, I was wondering if I could convert it into corrective shapes. Is there a way to isolate preserve volume's deformation after posing a bone and make a shape key out of it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable *Corrective Shape Keys* addon
2. Set target pose or animation to the rig
3. Select model. Turn on *Preserve Volume*
4. Duplicate model
5. Select the copy. Delete all shape keys. Apply *Armature* modifier
6. Select first object. Turn off *Preserve Volume*. Create and select new shape key
7. Select second and first models. In *Shape Key Specials* select *Add as corrective pose-shape*
8. Done! Unpin *Shape Key Lock*. Now you have preserve volume's deformation in the shape key.